# Characterization of sets in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Theorem: 
For any subset $M\neq\emptyset$ of a Hilbert space $H$, the span of $M$ is dense in $H$ if and only if $M^\perp=\{0\}$

For me, $M^\perp=\{0\}$ shows that only zero vector is orthogonal the subspace $M$ if $M$ is dense in $H$.

What does this mean geometrically, or intuitively?

Comment: Since $\overline{M}^\perp=M^\perp$.

Comment: The inner product $\langle\phantom x, \phantom x\rangle$ is continuous. Therefore for any $w \in H$, the function $f_w : v \mapsto \langle v, w\rangle$ is also continuous. And so $f_v^{-1}(0)$ is closed.